# Is java jlink endian specific?

Tags: java, jlink

There seems to be no documentation around this. In jlink, you can specify whether you want the image to be big or little endian. If you do not specify anything, native byte order is used.

I can build an image and specify no endian, or little and it runs (I'm on an i7 based machine), if I specify big endian there is an error during initialisation as Object cannot be found. Thus it doesn't appear to be capable of detecting the mismatch and reversing the endianness.

Looking under the hood at jlink, in jimage ImageStream it allocates ByteBuffers in order to write out the image. These are endian specific.

The endian that is passed in is either what you specify, defaulting to  ByteOrder.nativeOrder() which is the endian of the underlying hardware.

Therefore it would seem to me that jlink breaks the idea of compile once, run anywhere as a jlink image linked on a little endian platform will not work on a big endian one and v/v.

Can anyone confirm my analysis is correct as I don't have a big endian platform handy to sanity check it.

Thanks,

Comment: This doesn’t answer the question, but is a relevant reference: [jlink --endian option description](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/tools/jlink.htm#GUID-CECAC52B-CFEE-46CB-8166-F17A8E9280E9__GUID-B5D01061-161E-4A1B-97E1-CBC32A771F44)

Comment: Another follow on question is how one might link when using a non-native endian. Can the jdk be converted (I'm guessing probably not), and it's more for producing custom images for hardware when a specific jdk or otherwise is being used. Just shame the developers waste time on options that no one can use because it's just not documented well enough.

Comment: `jlink` output is platform-bound. You unlikely have a big-endian x86 CPU.